# Growth Of Distinct Users Per Week

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get a report that shows distinct users per week to show user growth per week, but I need it to show cumulative distinct users.

So if I have 5 weeks of data, I want to show:
Distinct users from week 0 through week 1
Distinct users from week 0 through week 2
Distinct users from week 0 through week 3
Distinct users from week 0 through week 4
Distinct users from week 0 through week 5

I have a whole year's worth of data. The only way I know how to do this is to literally query the time ranges adjusting a week out at a time and this is very tedious. I just can't figure out how I could query everything from week 0 through week 1 all the way to week 0 through week 52.

EDIT - What I have so far:

```
select count(distinct user_id) as count
from tracking
where datepart(wk,login_dt_tm) >= 0 and datepart(wk,login_dt_tm) <= 1
```

Then I take that number, record it, and update it to -- datepart(wk,login_dt_tm) <= 2. And so on until I have all the weeks. That way I can chart a nice growth chart by week.

This is tedious and there has to be another way.

UPDATE-
I used the solution provided by @siyual but updated it to use a table variable so I could get all the results in one output.

```
Declare @Week Int = 0
Declare @Totals Table
(
    WeekNum int,
    UserCount int
)
While @Week < 52
Begin
insert into @Totals (WeekNum,UserCount)
        select @Week,count(distinct user_id) as count
        from tracking
        where datepart(wk,login_dt_tm) >= @Week and datepart(wk,login_dt_tm) <= (@Week + 1)

    Set @Week += 1
End
Select * from @Totals
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
Declare @Week Int = 1

While @Week <= 52
Begin
    select count(distinct user_id) as count
    from tracking
    where datepart(wk,login_dt_tm) >= 0 and datepart(wk,login_dt_tm) <= @Week
    Set @Week += 1
End
```

Comment: I didn't even think about that. I added a table variable to it so I could just export the results.

Answer (score 2):

Why not something like:

```
 select count(distinct user_id) as count, datepartk(wk, login_dt_tm) as week
 from tracking
 group by datepart(wk,login_dt_tm)
 order by week
```

Comment: This is what I started down, but this gives me the distinct count of users per week, not across all weeks. 

For example, week 30 would be the count of users that week, not the count of users from week 0 to 30.

Comment: @TrialAndError sorry, I misunderstood your original question.  glad Siyual could help

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, I would do this in one statement, using a recursive CTE to generate the numbers from 1 to 52 (you could also use a numbers table):

```
with numbers as (
      select 1 as n
      union all
      select n + 1
      from numbers
      where n < 52
    )
select count(distinct user_id) as count
from tracking t join
     numbers n
     on datepart(wk, login_dt_tm) >= 0 and datepart(wk, login_dt_tm) <= numbers.n;
```

Seems easier to put it all in one query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  week_num,
  distinct_count
FROM (
  select distinct
    datepart(wk,login_dt_tm) week_num
  from @tracking
) t_week
CROSS APPLY (
  select
    count(distinct user_id) distinct_count
  from @tracking
  where datepart(wk,login_dt_tm) between 0 and t_week.week_num
) t_count
```